# Scanner error runtime

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i am experiencing some issues when launching this code. it keeps giving me error! i have added the exception if the file are not found. but it won't work... thanks a lot

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GestoreLotteria {
    public static ArrayList<Utente> listaUtenti = new ArrayList<>();
    public static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void inserisciUtenti() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("utenti.txt"));
        while (scnr.hasNextLine()){
            String nome = scnr.next();
            String cognome = scnr.next();
            String city = scnr.next();
            int giorno = rnd.nextInt(28);
            int mese = rnd.nextInt(12);
            int anno = 1996 - rnd.nextInt(72);
            String eta = giorno + " " + mese + " " + anno;
            Utente utente = new Utente(nome, cognome, city, eta);
            listaUtenti.add(utente);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        inserisciUtenti();
        System.out.print(listaUtenti);
    } 
}
```

the error is this

```
~/Desktop/TestEsameLPI/lotteri> java GestoreLotteria
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at GestoreLotteria.inserisciUtenti(GestoreLotteria.java:14)
    at GestoreLotteria.main(GestoreLotteria.java:28)
```

here is the utente.java  class

```
public class Utente {
    public String nome;
    public String cognome;
    public String city;
    public String eta;

    public Utente(String nome, String cognome, String city, String eta) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.cognome = cognome;
            this.city = city;
            this.eta = eta;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome; 
    }

    public String getCognome(){
        return cognome;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public String getEta(){
        return eta;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't recognize the scanner? Are you seeing a compiler error? A runtime exception? Unexpected behavior? Something else?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception so needs to be explicitly thrown (or caught)

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question. Its not compile time error. U can whether scnr.next() exists before assigning it to your variable.

```
public static void inserisciUtenti() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("testfile.txt"));
        String nome = "";
        String cognome = "";
        String city = "";


        while (scnr.hasNextLine()){
            if(scnr.hasNext())
                 nome = scnr.next().toString();
            if(scnr.hasNext())
             cognome = scnr.next().toString();
            if(scnr.hasNext())
             city = scnr.next().toString();
            int giorno = rnd.nextInt(28);
            int mese = rnd.nextInt(12);
            int anno = 1996 - rnd.nextInt(72);`enter code here`
            String eta = giorno + " " + mese + " " + anno;
            Utente utente = new Utente(nome, cognome, city, eta);
            listaUtenti.add(utente);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Could you try adding print statements. Please share your file content as well

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your file "utenti.txt" start with an empty line?
If it is so, then right after this test

```
while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
```

the only thing you know is that there is a **line** available in the file, so that the next command

```
String nome = scnr.next();
```

fails to get a `String` token and produces the `NoSuchElementException` that you get.
As a general rule, before calling `String whatever = scnr.next()`, you should test using `scnr.hasNext()` instead of `scnr.hasNextLine()`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle all the exceptions "that could be thrown" during the course of execution of your program..In your case, the Java compiler is screaming - "YOUR CODE MIGHT THROW FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION, SO HANDLE IT SOMEHOW. PERIOD" So, you have 2 options...

```
1. Say that your method "throws" FileNotFoundEception by adding it to the method's signature..
                     OR
2. put a "try-catch" block around the code which might throw this exception..
```

Comment: @user3190369 - the scanner might not be getting the next element correctly.. are  you sure that the file has correct elements??. BTW where have you defined - "Utente"?

Comment: i made an utente class

Comment: and utente is in the same file?

Comment: utente class is in Utente.java , another file in the same folder